# Connecting to an existing SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm trying to do the same as on this tutorial:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
But i'm facing some difficulties.
Here is my class:

```
public class TechAgrumeSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {    



      //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.test.test/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "Player_Club";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;
    private static final String TABLE_PLAYERS = "Player";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NOM = "nom_Player";
    private static final String KEY_SURNOM = "surnom_Player";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "age_Player";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public TechAgrumeSQLiteHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        Log.d("I'm here: ","I'm here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
            Log.d("Copy BD","database already exists!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();
                        Log.d("Copy BD","Datbase copied!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{



    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.



        void addPlayer(Player player) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NOM, player.getNom_Player()); // Contact Name
            values.put(KEY_SURNOM, player.getSurnom_Player()); // Contact Phone
            values.put(KEY_AGE, player.getAge_Player()); // Contact Phone

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_PLAYERS, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }

        public List<Player> getAllPlayers() {
            List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYERS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Player player = new Player();
                    player.setCode_Player(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    player.setNom_Player(cursor.getString(1));
                    player.setSurnom_Player(cursor.getString(2));
                    player.setAge_Player(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    playerList.add(player);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            return playerList;
        }

}
```

And here is the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TechAgrumeSQLiteHelper db=new TechAgrumeSQLiteHelper(this);
    //this.deleteDatabase("Player_Club.db");
    // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ................................................");
        db.addPlayer(new Player("nom1", "prénom1",25));
        db.addPlayer(new Player("nom2", "prénom2",24));
        db.addPlayer(new Player("nom3", "prénom3",26));
        db.addPlayer(new Player("nom4", "prénom4",16));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Player> player = db.getAllPlayers();       

        for (Player cn : player) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getCode_Player()+" ,Name: " + cn.getNom_Player() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getSurnom_Player()+"  ,Age: "+cn.getAge_Player();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);}}
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
D/I'm here:   ( 6548): I'm here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
D/KeyguardViewMediator(  216): setHidden false
D/Copy BD( 6548): database already exists!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
D/Insert: ( 6548): Inserting ................................................
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp( 6548): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Player, db=/data/data/test.test.test/databases/webview.db
E/SQLiteDatabase( 6548): Error during inserting
E/SQLiteDatabase( 6548): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Player: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Player(surnom_Player,nom_Player,age_Player) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

I went to look if the Player_Club.db really exists:

```
    adb shell
    shell@android:/ $ run-as test.test.test
    run-as test.test.test
    <a href="mailto:shell@android:/data/data/test.test.test">shell@android:/data/data/test.test.test</a> $ cd /data/data/test.test.test/databases
    .test.test/databases                                                          <
    <a href="mailto:shell@android:/data/data/test.test.test">shell@android:/data/data/test.test.test</a>/databases $ ls
    ls
   Player_Club.db
   webview.db
   webview.db-shm
   webview.db-wal
```

From these lines i can tell that the database really exists, so i don't know why it's looking for the Player table on the webview.db?

Comment: I would recommend switching to SQLiteAssetHelper: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: from log cat error db=/data/data/test.test.test/databases/webview.db means ur database name is webview.db but u hav mentioned Player_Club.db as ur db name.so check your database name in ddms and check in yoyr assest folder too